# How to generate PDF from a Google Sheet and send copies to specific email accounts when a specific cell in the sheet is edited?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, spreadsheet

I am trying to make an invoice for a project. The way it works is a person would fill in the required details and as soon as the details are filled. They would edit a specific cell (could be a drop-down like "invoice filled" and "invoice incomplete"). As soon as they click on filled, it would send the sheet as a PDF file to different emails.

I'm having a hard time going around this through apps scripts.

Comment: share your spreadsheet

Comment: @MikeSteelson I would but is there a way we could connect and u could help me out in this? I would appreciate it if that could happen. Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7UvoKHf8q3Pkp2ZM7ZfVBSrhbn-AJUb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108012013075745298698&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: your sheet in an xlsx file, I can't help you on this.

Comment: @MikeSteelson https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAwyIuy3myOkt64fyjf3mVMroU3eADRPrGT-pd9gR4g/edit?usp=sharing check now

Comment: Try the function I have added to your project. Give the email address first

Comment: @MikeSteelson THANKS! you have been a great help!

Comment: @MikeSteelson sure, i did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample

```
function createAndSendPDF() {
  const docID = '___________'; // ID of spreadsheet
  const feuilleID = '0'; // sheetID
  const email = 'emailAddress@email.com';
  // const dossier = DriveApp.getFolderById('____________'); // ID of Folder if you want to save a copy of the pdf file
  const d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMMdd")
  const fichier = 'myFileName' + "_" + d + ".pdf"
  const objet = 'Test pdf';
  const corps = "Please find ...";

  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + docID + '/export?';
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
    '&size=A4' + 
    '&portrait=true' +
    '&fitw=true' +
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' +
    '&fzr=false' +
    '&gid=' + feuilleID;
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions, params).getBlob();

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, objet, corps, {
      htmlBody: corps,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: fichier,
            content: reponse.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });

  // dossier.createFile(reponse.setName(fichier));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a trigger of type [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and control when the checkbox value is set to true.

Then you basically need to send an email with the attachment:

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Proforma Sheet')
const PDF_MIME = "application/pdf"
const listEmail = ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"]

const sendPDF = (e) => {
  const { range: { rowStart, columnStart } } = e
  const {value} = e
  if (rowStart === 11 && columnStart === 12 && value === "TRUE" ) {
    const copy = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs(PDF_MIME).copyBlob()
    listEmail.forEach(email=>{
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Your Spreadsheet", "See attched", {
        attachments: [copy]
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And create an [installable edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) for the `sendPDF` function.